# how to remove certain character or select certain index character in string?

Tags: java, string

I have this string,

```
anyType{image0=images/articles/4_APRIL_BLACK_copy.jpg; image1=images/articles/4_APRIL_COLOR_copy.jpg; }
```

What i want is only

```
"images/articles/4_APRIL_BLACK_copy.jpg"
```

How do i get this?

Comment: Is this a real question? Can't believe this.

Comment: @userIsAMonkey: Believe it. It actually is. ;-)

Comment: seriously, yes. I got on idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I perform a split in my app.

```
String link = "image0=images/articles/4_APRIL_BLACK_copy.jpg";
    String[] parts = link.split("=");

    String first = parts[0];
    Log.v("FIRST", first);

    String second = parts[1];
    Log.v("SECOND", second);
```

This method will split your string into 2 at the **"="** and give you 2 split strings. In your case, the `String second` is the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
s.split("=")[1]
```

You are splitting the string on `=` which would return substrings in an array. The second element is what you need.